# How to add/remove from a firestore map field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As listed in documentation, there is a way to update map fields using dot notation here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

But It didn't mention a way to add or remove from them.
The solution in mind is to read the map field, add to it and rewrite the map again.
Is this the way to go ? Or there is another more efficient way to do it like with arrays as mentioned here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're suggesting that `update()` doesn't work for adding new map field values as you saw in the linked documentation, try a set with merge:

```java
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("map.property", "value");
docRef.set(update, SetOptions.merge());
```

To remove, use `FieldValue.delete()` as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields):

```java
Map<String,Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("map.property", FieldValue.delete());
docRef.update(update);
```

Comment: OK, That's clear now
One more question, If I am doing a writebatch, can I reuse the hash map object that I create to set updates like the 'update' map in your example or should I craete a new one each time I am submitting different updates.
What I mean by 'reusing' is to clear the map and populating it with different data instead of creating a new one. Is there an issue with that ? Is it safe ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.